# Preset D flip flop as 0 for total sum

Tags: flipflop, adder

I'm trying to implement a total sum that follows this code

```
SUM = SUM + INPUT
```

SUM and INPUT are 5 bit signals in binary. I know how to implement the adder and i have 5 D flip flops to store SUM but at the start of the system, SUM is not defined because the input to SUM uses the output from the adder which uses SUM and so on and so forth. I'm not sure how to initialize my SUM to be all 0's. Any advice for building this circuit in general would be appreciated outside of my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a reset signal. Do your D flip flops have a reset input? If not, then you need to create your own reset signal by using logic gates to force the input to the flops to be 0.

Comment: So what signals do i put for CLEAR(RESET) and PRESET? From what i understand the only way we can force a signal is if any of the inputs to the NAND gates are 0, in which case it outputs 1. How can i use NAND gates to force a 0?

Comment: So do your flip flops have CLEAR(RESET) and PRESET inputs? If so, you don't need to add gates before the D input.

Comment: I'm building this in a schematic in Xilinx so I've just added the CLEAR and RESET inputs myself.

Comment: I didn't mean using a NAND gate, I mean using whatever combination of logic gates (NAND/NOR/AND/OR/NOT etc.) you need to make the value 0. I think you could do D[i]=originalD[i] AND (NOT RESET).

Comment: You don't need both CLEAR and RESET, one or the other should do.

Comment: Think I've got it working. Thanks :)

Comment: On an unrelated note to this question, would you have any idea how to just send a single pulse of the CLEAR signal at the start?

Comment: How are you writing your testbench? Verilog, VHDL?

Comment: Verilog. Do i manually flick it on then off for a tiny bit with an input?

Comment: Well, it is an input. You can just do something like: `initial begin reset = 1'b1; #5ns; reset = 1'b0; end`

Comment: @Justin, your first comment is fine as an answer - why not post it?

Comment: @hacktastical - Thanks, I've posted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reset signal. If your flip flops have a reset input, you can just use that. Otherwise, you need to create your own reset signal by using logic gates to force the input to the flops to be 0.